# Windows Settings > Devices crashes. Alternative for Bluetooth?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, crash

I'm trying to get some Bluetooth headphones working on Windows 10 x64 Build 18362.900, but whenever I open **Settings > Devices** there is a brief pause (less than 1s), then **Settings** crashes.

**Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application** shows the following error:

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.18362.628, time stamp: 0x066bf1a5
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.18362.815, time stamp: 0xb29ecf52
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000008c45f
Faulting process ID: 0x1d98
Faulting application start time: 0x01d642e5f6932be4
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: cb32864a-fad7-40be-9623-927a99b21869
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.2.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

There are no obvious problems in **Device Manager**.

- Is there an alternative method to reach settings for Bluetooth devices?
- Is there a known fix for the **Settings > Devices** crash? There is no known Windows update to download which fixes this.

### Update 1

In **Explorer** pointing to C:\Windows\System32, I double-clicked each "Control panel item" (*.cpl) in turn. They all showed something except `irprops.cpl` (which showed nothing at all) and `bthprops.cpl` (which briefly shows Settings and then crashes).

### Update 2

Following advice from a web search (this problem is super common), I ran the following from the command prompt with admin rights:

- DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
- SFC /ScanNow

This took about 60 minutes and after completing, I rebooted the system. There is no change - **Settings > Devices** still crashes.

### Update 3

The problem seems to be related to the `bthprops.cpl` **Control Panel** applet. If I open a command prompt in `C:\Windows\System32` and run `main.cpl`, Mouse settings are displayed fine. But `bthprops.cpl` results in **Settings** starting to appear and then it crashes. **Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application** shows that `C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe` crashed.

### Update 4

Have tried all suggestions I came across and Bluetooth simply does not work on both Windows 10 and Windows 8.1. Tested on four different systems (3xWindows 10 and 1xWindows 8.1). On Windows 8.1, for example, `PC Settings > PC and devices > Bluetooth` results in an immediate crash on the Windows Settings app (as on Windows 10).

Windows appears to have stopped supporting Bluetooth. I'll use wired headphones on Windows and Bluetooth headphones on Ubuntu going forward.

Comment: _**NT Status** 0xC0000409 (-1073740791) **Windows Error** 0x502 (1282) **NT Status Message:** The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application._

Comment: Interesting, but can that information help diagnose or debug the problem? For example, does that possibly indicate this is an anti-virus problem?

Comment: I don't know but it gives you an avenue to explore. Anything to do with Bluetooth..

Comment: @AlainD General FYI: `/StartComponentCleanup` needs to be run prior to `/RestoreHealth`; `/ScanHealth` isn't needed _(`/RestoreHealth` scans the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`], which is what `/ScanHealth` does, fixing any corruption [mismatched hashes] it finds w/ a good copy from Windows' Update servers - it's why `/RestoreHealth` should be run while connected to the internet)_. As to the issue, you may want to try a Repair Install of Windows - Download the Windows ISO via the Media Creation Tool > Save as an ISO > Extract ISO's contents > Run `setup.exe` _(while booted to Windows)_.

Comment: It says here (https://windowsreport.com/settings-app-crash-windows-10/) that you can solve the Settings crashing issue by renaming C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel to ImmersiveControlPanel.old. I'm pretty sure you need to do that as admin, but then running a regular sfc /scannow (as admin...) will prompt Windows to exhume a clean copy of Settings from the image it keeps stowed away. The strange thing with your problem is that it seems circumvented to BT. Have you tried to uninstall/reinstall your BT interface from Device Manager after restarting your PC? Could be just a bad driver.

Comment: Update: None of the suggestions work. `Windows Settings > Devices` continues to crash and I am not able to access or view Bluetooth settings on Windows 10. There may be some dependent service not running? The answer at least provides a workaround to access other settings in `Devices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings > Devices` has several pages. On my installation these are:

- Bluetooth & other devices
- Printers & scanners
- Mouse
- Typing
- AutoPlay
- USB

The first page (`Bluetooth`) is the first page and therefore displayed first by default. If this page is crashing, you will not able to display any of the other pages in `Settings > Devices` directly.

While this doesn't solve your Bluetooth problems, a workaround to access `Printers & scanners` is with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and the command:

```
ms-settings:printers
```

You'll then be able to view printers, mouse and other device pages. Alternatively, add the following to a batch file:

```
@echo off
start ms-settings:printers
```

For information, the command for Bluetooth would be:

```
ms-settings:bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was two services:

DeviceAssociationBrokerSvc and DeviceFlow. Make sure to enable both from in the register in path

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
```

And set the "Start" to 3 and reboot. (Don’t shutdown and then power on, just reboot.)

By the way, this is what happens when one messes with the registry.

Comment: This fixes the problem! The full paths are `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DeviceAssociationBrokerSvc\Start=3` and `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DevicesFlowUserSvc\Start=3`

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem after using Blackbird software (Windows 10 privacy thing). I don't know, what helped, but I did following:

1. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DeviceAssociationService start=2`
2. `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DeviceAssociationBrokerSvc\Start=3`
3. `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DevicesFlowUserSvc\Start=3`

Points 2 and 3 I got from [Ivanex's](https://superuser.com/a/1784292/167207) and Toto's answer.